# How to navigate pages via electron menu - angularjs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am new to electron, How to navigate between local pages using electron menu

```
{
        label: 'Help',
        submenu: [
            {
                label: 'About',
                click(menuItem, browserWindow, event) {
                    browserWindow.loadURL('/about')
                }
            },
            {
                label: package.name + '-' + package.version,
                enabled: false
            }
        ]
    }
```

How to navigate to a page locally on clicking about menu

Answer (score 1):

One way I found using electron's remote method

main.js (electron file)

```
window.setMenu(null);
```

app.js (controller)

```
const { app, remote } = require('electron')
const { Menu, MenuItem } = remote;

var menuCtrl = function ($scope, $state) {

    const template = [
        {
            label: 'Help',
            submenu: [
                {
                    label: 'About',
                    click() {
                        $state.go('about')
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    // Menu
    const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);

};

menuCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$state'];

module.exports = menuCtrl;
```

Answer (score 1):

When using AngularJS, you can also write it as

```
label: 'Help',
    submenu: [
        {
            label: 'About',
            click(menuItem, browserWindow, event) {
                browserWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/index.html#/about`)
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've got there is fine except you should put the full url in the `.loadURL` function like `https://stackoverflow.com/tour/`

Comment: Yeah. I have a simple html page loaded from local . I wanted to navigate within that.

Comment: What is the url you are loading to start with?

Comment: Check the solution I posted.